# How to use the NavigationView and NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am setting NavigationLink for Item,but not work with image disappeared.

```
struct Items: View {

    var landmarks: [Landmark]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(landmarks) { landmark in
                    //加了这个导航就看不到图片了，CategoryHome 也不显示图片，
                    //NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                        Item(landmark: landmark)
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed your `Scrollview` into a `NavigationView` or it will not work

```
struct Items: View {

var landmarks: [Landmark]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(landmarks) { landmark in
                    //加了这个导航就看不到图片了，CategoryHome 也不显示图片，
                    NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                        Item(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation) is the apple tutorial for creating navigation is `SwiftUI`